# Popular uma tabela com dados de formulario em angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou aprendendo angular.js e estou tendo dificuldades com o codigo seguinte

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", [])

myapp.controller('controller', function reset($scope){
  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.nome = " ";
    $scope.nota1 = " ";
    $scope.nota2 = " ";
  }
  $scope.reset();
});

myapp.controller('controller', function enviar($scope){
  $scope.enviar = function(){
    nome = $scope.nome;
    nota1 = $scope.nota1;
    nota2 = $scope.nota2;
    media = $scope.media;
    situacao = $scope.situacao;
    media = (nota1 + nota2)/2;
    if (media >= 10){
      situacao = "Aprovado";
    } else if (media > 0 && media < 8 ){
      situacao = "Reprovado";
    } else {
      situacao = "Em exame";
    }
    var $scope.student = {
      nome, nota1, nota2, media, situacao
    };

  }
  $scope.enviar();
});
```

Sempre que coloco os dados no formulário ele não actualiza a tabela

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cadastro.js"></script>
    <title>Cadastro de Notas</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app= "myapp" ng-controller= "controller">
    <form action="index.html" method="GET">
      <p>
        <label for="studentname">Nome do estudante:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" ng-model="student.name"/><br />

        <label for="nota1">Primeira nota</label>
        <input type="number" id="nota1" ng-model="student.nota1"/><br />

        <label for="nota2">Segunda nota</label>
        <input type="number" id="nota2" ng-model="student.nota2"/><br />

        <button ng-click="enviar()">Enviar</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Apagar</button>
      </p>
    </form>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Nota 1</th>
        <th>Nota 2</th>
        <th>Media</th>
        <th>Situacao</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-bind>
        <th>{{nome}}</th>
        <th>{{nota1}}</th>
        <th>{{nota2}}</th>
        <th>{{media}}</th>
        <th>{{situacao}}</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Por favor ajude-me obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Você fez errado, mas, pelo que eu entendi você quer gravar uma lista de estudantes, decidindo se ele foi aprovado ou não pela média.

Estude o angular de maneira progressiva, que aos poucos você vai entender o seu funcionamento, perceba que no meu exemplo o código muda muito.

Fiz um exemplo básico, sem conferir se a digitação está correta, então, digite nas médias números inteiros para dar certo.

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.student = [];
  
  $scope.name = "";
  
  $scope.nota1 = "";
  
  $scope.nota2 = "";
  
  console.log($scope.student);

  $scope.enviar = function(name, nota1, nota2) {

    var media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2

    var situacao = media > 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado';

    $scope.student.push({
      'nome': name,
      'nota1': nota1,
      'nota2': nota2,
      'media': media,
      'situacao': situacao
    });
    
    $scope.reset();
    
  }

  $scope.reset = function() {
    
    $scope.name = "";
    
    $scope.nota1 = "";
    
    $scope.nota2 = "";
    
  }

  $scope.reset();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <form action="index.html" method="POST">
    <p>
      <label for="studentname">Nome do estudante:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" ng-model="name" />
      <br />

      <label for="nota1">Primeira nota</label>
      <input type="number" id="nota1" ng-model="nota1" />
      <br />

      <label for="nota2">Segunda nota</label>
      <input type="number" id="nota2" ng-model="nota2" />
      <br />

      <button ng-click="enviar(name, nota1, nota2);">Enviar</button>
      <button ng-click="reset()">Apagar</button>
    </p>
  </form>
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Nota 1</th>
      <th>Nota 2</th>
      <th>Media</th>
      <th>Situacao</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in student" ng-if="x.nome">
      <th>{{x.nome}}</th>
      <th>{{x.nota1}}</th>
      <th>{{x.nota2}}</th>
      <th>{{x.media}}</th>
      <th>{{x.situacao}}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Existe várias formas de implementar isso, mas, essa foi bem simples para que você entenda `$scope`, `ng-repeat` e `ng-if`. No próprio [site](https://angularjs.org/) tem exemplos.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Tens algumas coisas erradas. Antes de mais, [aqui está o codigo a funcionar](http://jsfiddle.net/v1o2zL03/).

Primeiro. Tu estás a definir o teu controlador duas vezes.
a primeira em `myapp.controller('controller', function reset($scope){` e uma segunda vez em `myapp.controller('controller', function enviar($scope){`.

Isto tem que ser só uma declaração, e de preferencia com uma função anónima:
`myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope){`

Depois disto, tu tens que juntar o codigo que estava nos "dois" controladores em um. (ve o fiddle);

```
nome = $scope.nome;
nota1 = $scope.nota1;
nota2 = $scope.nota2;
media = $scope.media;
situacao = $scope.situacao;
```

Estas declarações têm que ter um `var` atrás.

```
var $scope.student = {
  nome, nota1, nota2, media, situacao
};
```

Aqui estás a redefinir o `$scope` o que é uma coisa péssima uma vez que partes o controlador todo e passa só a existir `student`. O que queres é `$scope.student` (repara que não tem `var` antes de `$scope`) que o que faz é adicionar uma propriedade nova ao `$scope` existente (ao invés de o reescrever).

`$scope.reset();` e `$scope.enviar();` estão a ser chamadas na inicialização da aplicação, eu não sei se queres que isso aconteça.

Vê o fiddle que está na primeira linha para veres o código correcto.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicacao. o tutorial que estou a seguir http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/index.htm
Tens uma proposta melhor ou dica para me dares para melhorar o aprendizado

Comment: @JohnMuconto se a explicação o ajudou, pfv bote aí um upavoto ;)

Comment: @JohnMuconto also, checka o http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-introduction-hello-world-tutorial/ ou procura por "hello, world angularjs" no google e começa por esses tutos :)

Comment: Por causa da minha reputação meus upavotos não aparecem, mas obrigado